Can I travel to Mexico with C1/D multiple entry visa?
I am from India. Can I travel to Mexico with C1/D multiple entry visa? Do I need any other visa to stay in Mexico? I want to stay for 7-10 days.

What  did your research show? Have you looked at https://www.indiainmexico.gov.in/public_files/assets/pdf/IMPORTANT_NOTICE_TO_INDIAN_NATIONALS_TRAVELLING_TO_MEXICO.pdf or https://www.iatatravelcentre.com/passport-visa-health-travel-document-requirements.htm ?

Everything seems to just say "a valid US visa" but it is somewhat surprising if that applies to every type of visa, including transit visas as in this case.  I can understand wanting explicit confirmation of that.

There was a recent question where a quote from the Mexican consulate specifically required a tourist visa.

This question is similar to: Mutistop flight to Mexico on F1 visa. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@littleadv Seems non-duplicative to me: an F visa is for study and remaining in the US, while C/D is for employment and may (but does not require) the visa-holder to remain in the US...and the OP here is asking about entering and staying in Mexico, not the US. OTOH, this question seems right on point.

This question is similar to: Can I travel Mexico with C1/D Visa?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Both rely on the same quote from the embassy in Finland
